# Swift WkWebView - Colors not displaying in WebView

Tags: html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a webView that must display a page that have a palette of colors. The colors of the page displays properly on a browser but not on my webView. Is there something wrong with my webView configurations? Thank you.

Device: iPad Pro - iPadOS 15.2

Deployment info: iOS 13.4

**Here is the code for the webView**

```
func setWebView() {
    
    let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    contentController.add(self, name: "appHandler")
    
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController
    
    self.webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "appHandler")
    self.webView.isOpaque = false
    self.webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    self.webView.uiDelegate = self
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
}
```

**Here is the HTML of the page for the individual box**

```
<div class="d-inline-block pe-5" style="width:50px">
    <div class="divBox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="0557b0" id="color0557b0" name="colors" style="
                                appearance: none;
                                width: 50px !important;
                                height: 50px !important;
                                background: #0557b0">
        <label for="color0557b0"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**It displays correctly on a browser**

[image]

**No color on my webView**

[image]